# Group Theory: group under the composition multiplication modulo $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose you have a group $G(S,*)$ where 
$S=\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$, $p$ is prime number, and
$*$ is equivalent to the multiplication$\mod p$.

If $a,b$ belong to $S$, then $ab\pmod{p}$ also belongs to $S$.

> Then is there a general formula for generating the inverses of each element in the set S?

For instance 
consider $S={1,2,3,4}$

then

$2^{-1}=3$

$3^{-1}=2$

$4^{-1}=4$ (This is obvious as $(p-1)*(p-1)$ is congruent to $1$ mod $p$)

But when the order of the group increases the $1$'s are distributed in a peculiar manner.

Comment: Not sure where the question is?

Comment: To be clear $G(S,\ast)=(\Bbb Z_p, \times)$ ?

Comment: There is no such general formula. $1^{-1} = 1$, $2^{-1} = \frac{p+1}{2}$, but what about $3$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza If you're willing to split into cases on whether $p$ is $1$ or $2$ mod $3$, you can still find such a formula.

Comment: @Meelo, no, I was talking about $p=3$

Answer (score 10):

This is not exactly a formula, but an algorithm.

If you want the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $p$, then you want to solve the equation $ax \equiv 1 \mod p$. Rewriting gives you $ax+bp=1$. This can be solved using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: Multiply $a^{p-2}$ both sides and apply Fermat's Little theorem, this will give the formula similar to @RiaD.

Answer (score 6):

A possible formula is $$a^{-1} \equiv a^{p-2} \mod p$$ because according to Fermat Little Theorem, $a^0 \equiv a^{p-1} \mod p$.

Comment: In addition, this can be easily generalised to compute inverses in any finite field.